# In commerce funds where is the fund getting deposited?

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

In commerce funds module there is an option to deposit funds. When clicked on this link it takes you to the payment gateway where you can enter the amount you want to deposit. My question is where is this amount getting deposited? I can see the account balance (point on the website) of the user getting increased by the deposited amount but is there a bank account where the deposited money is transferred to?

Comment: That is a good question. I'd suppose the checkout uses Drupal commerce's payment gateways. So I'd expect it to go where you've configured your commerce payments to go to. Did you enable any payment method?